# Using desktop-mode with Emacs Daemon

Tags: daemon, desktop

I am using emacs 24.3 (ubuntu 14.10) and would like the daemon to participate in the graphical desktop session lifecycle while using `desktop-mode`. I went through http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon but it still does not play nice for me. One problem is that the daemon SIGTERM termination does not clean up `.emacs.desktop.lock` so the next start will refuse to pick up the saved state.

Does anyone have a recipe to make emacs daemon + desktop mode play nice with the graphical desktop session?

As a sidenote: Sending SIGHUP frequently crashes emacs for me.

Answer (score 6):

Don't kill the process.

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kill-emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd> to terminate the server.

Comment: Ok, that cleans up the look. I may be missing something, but how does one execute that termination of the graphical session? The easiest thing I could think of would be a custom OS signal handler.

Comment: If you have an active client frame, you can issue `kill-emacs` directly. If you have no current clients, you can run `emacsclient -e '(kill-emacs)'`. If you just want Emacs to shut down more gracefully when killed by a signal, you'll probably need to `M-x report-emacs-bug` (after checking to see whether it's already been logged).

Comment: Sure. The thing is that I do not want to bother and manually tell every program to shut down gracefully. Desktop session managers do tell programs the session is about to terminate. I want emacs to automatically take action at that time.

Comment: Well check the bug reports, report a new one if necessary, and once you have more information, update the question, or post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it for me: (you need to disable elsewhere desktop-save-mode)

```
(require 'desktop)
;; (setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)

(if (not (daemonp))
    (desktop-save-mode 1)
  (defun restore-desktop (frame)
    "Restores desktop and cancels hook after first frame opens. 
     So the daemon can run at startup and it'll still work"
    (with-selected-frame frame
      (desktop-save-mode 1)
      (desktop-read)
      (remove-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'restore-desktop)))
  (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'restore-desktop))
```

Uncomment first line if you get the `Error (frameset): Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`.

Btw, use `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-M-c") 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)` to leave emacsclient safely.

Comment: Thats not enabling it if it starts via emacsclient though is it?